# Covering group of $\mathrm{PSL}(3,4)$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\mathrm{PSL}(3,4)$. I have found the Schur multiplier of $G$ is $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ by looking up some books. Now I wonder the  universal covering group of $G$. Is there anyone who can tell me ? Or where can I find the information of it?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Isn't that section of the wikipedia article just referring to the real and complex numbers? I think ${\rm PSL}(3,4)$ is an exception to most general statements of that kind.

Comment: I find it difficult to know exactly what is being asked here. The covering group of $G$ is a perfect group $H$ with centre $ Z(H) \cong C_3 \times C_4^2$ and $H/Z(H) \cong {\rm PSL}(3,4)$. What specifically would  you like to know about it? The ATLAS of Finite Groups is the best general reference for properties of covering groups of finite simple groups, but it is not completely easy to read.

Comment: I wonder the generators and relations of it. Can I get it from the ATLAS? @DerekHolt

Comment: Unfortunately the only presentation given in the ATLAS is for $12_2.L_3(4)$, which has cyclic centre of order $12$. I will see if I can easily extend that to a presentation of the full covering group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the covering group of ${\rm PSL}(3,4)$ in GAP, either as a subgroup of $S_{511}$ or as a finite presentation (on the same generating sets) using one of the commands:

```
G := PerfectGroup(IsPermGroup,967680,4);
G := PerfectGroup(IsSubgroupFpGroup,967680,4);
```

You can do the same in Magma with

```
D := PerfectGroupDatabase();
G := PermutationGroup(D,967680,4);
G := Group(D,967680,4);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But could you tell me how do you know the required group is the fourth group of order 967680 in the database?

Comment: You can calculate the composition factors of each of the groups of that order until you hit the right one. With the GAP groups you can also tell from the name of the group.

Comment: Is GAP able to calculate and display the character table of G := PerfectGroup(IsPermGroup,967680,4); in a reasonable amount of time? Or do you know a place to find the character table for SchurCover(PSL(3,4))? I tried to display the table for SchurCover(PSL(3,4)) and got many "#I  Coset table calculation failed -- trying with bigger table limit" messages. But maybe the way you present the group here it will be quick to find the character table?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira That seems to be a new question, not a comment on my answer.

Comment: OK I asked a new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4582239/character-table-for-schur-cover-of-sz8