# Character Tables for large quasisimple groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, gap, simple-groups

The smallest Suzuki group, $ Sz(8) $, is a simple finite group of order
$$
29120
$$
The Schur multiplier of $ Sz(8) $ is $ 2 \times 2 $. So the Schur cover of $ Sz(8) $ is a quasisimple group of order
$$
116480
$$
(it is the only quasisimple group of that order, in fact it is the only perfect group of that order)

When looking for the character table of a quasi simple group GAP usually struggles to display the character table of SchurCover(G). For example GAP displays multiple

"#I  Coset table calculation failed -- trying with bigger table limit"

errors before finally giving up when I try to directly compute the character table for the Schur cover of $ G:=Sz(8) $. I originally encountered the same issue for $ SchurCover(PSL(3,4)) $. But as Derek Holt points out in this question

[Covering group of $\mathrm{PSL}(3,4)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325796/covering-group-of-mathrmpsl3-4/3328868?noredirect=1#comment9645665_3328868)

$ SchurCover(PSL(3,4)) $ is easily recognized as

$$
PerfectGroup(967680,4)
$$

To my great surprise GAP is able to calculate and display the character table of $ PerfectGroup(967680,4) $ in only a few seconds.

I have identified $ SchurCover(Sz(8)) $ as $ PerfectGroup(116480,1) $. Strangely GAP is struggling to display the character table for  $ PerfectGroup(116480,1) $ even though the group is an order of magnitude smaller than $ PerfectGroup(967680,4) $

How can I display the character table for the Schur cover of $ Sz(8) $? Is there a better approach to finding it in GAP?

If not does anyone know a reference for the character table of the Schur cover of $ Sz(8) $?

Comment: I just tried it in GAP. Computing the character table took about $0.4$ seconds, and displaying it took a further $25$ seconds. You can find the character table of $2 \cdot {\rm Sz}(8)$ in the ATLAS, and that is sufficient to compute it for the full cover, because all characters have kernel of order at least $2$.

Comment: If you are using a version of GAP before 4.12, you need to make sure you get the perfect group as permutation group: `PerfectGroup(IsPermGroup,116480,1);` -- what you already observed is that the finitely presented version of the cover does not behave well.

Comment: WOW that worked perfectly!!!!!!(pun intended ;) Thanks @ahulpke Also I should have known that including the IsPermGroup part was important because Derek Holt made a point of doing it in his previous answer.  Thanks Derek Holt! Also very interesting point from Derek Holt that $ 2^2.Sz(8) $ has no faithful irreps since a quasisimple finite group has a faithful irrep if and only if the center is cyclic https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4377934/does-every-quasisimple-finite-group-have-a-faithful-complex-irrep